# Is r.js dependency tracing significantly slower since v2.1.16? Or is it just me?

Tags: performance, requirejs, amd

I have noticed a dramatic increase in build time in r.js versions 2.1.16/2.1.17, as compared to 2.1.15 and before. The extra time seems to be spend during the 'Tracing dependencies for...' fase.

My `build.js` looks something like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: 'some/path/here',
    mainConfigFile: 'some/path/here',
    dir: 'some/path/here',
    modules: [
        {
            name: "base"
        },
        {
            name: "specific",
            exclude: ["base"]
        }
    ],
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    removeCombined: true,
    skipDirOptimize: true,
    optimize: "none"
})
```

In run this build using node.js in a Windows environment. Both `base` and `specific` have a decent (but not absurd) amount of nested dependencies (`base` is referenced internally in `specific`, and is therefore excluded). In 2.1.15 this build would take **±2 seconds** on my system; in 2.1.16/2.1.17 it takes **±8 seconds**. (note that all uglification has been disabled, so this is not a factor)

I include this `build.js` for reference, but I don't think it is actually my settings that cause the slowdown. I have tried many (simple) scenarios and they all seem to be a lot slower at tracing dependencies on 2.1.16/2.1.17.

Anyone have this happening too? Or is it just me? I'm pretty sure that while my project grows, this **4x** increase in build time will start to annoy me exponentially, so please advice :-)

Comment: I second the observation. I downgraded r.js on my project to 2.1.15 and shaved off 2/3rds of the build time. My build also uses node on Windows, in my case Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue on Linux with `findNestedDependencies: true`.
The issue is reported here https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/850

The following release info is mentioned here http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html. This is the most likely reason for the issue.

> 2.1.16
>
> The notable changes are in the r.js optimizer:
>
> Esprima 2.0 is used by the optimizer when parsing modules for dependencies. This allows some ES6 features to be used. Whatever is parsable by Esprima 2.0 is what is supported (when running in xpcshell, Reflect.parse is still used).

Comment: The above reason seems to be confirmed by the author of r.js (jrburke) in the linked github issue. Because r.js currently has a high priority for using a parser that supports ES6 features, something like Esprima is needed. The author says he currently has no bandwidth to explore alternatives to Esprima (like Acorn). He does mention that performance might improve with new releases of Esprima, but that that is up to the Esprima team. Because this seems to be the situation for the foreseeable future, without a known workaround, I will mark this as the accepted answer until anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [the latest r.js snapshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrburke/r.js/master/dist/r.js). jrburke says [this change](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/pull/900) brings a significant improvement.

from the [github issue comment](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js/issues/850#issuecomment-194513328):

> [PR] #900 just landed a change that seems to really reduce time spent
>   in the parsing steps. If people that had slow build times want to try
>   out the latest master snapshot …